# Are SagePay merchantSessionKeys and cardIdentifiers OK to expose to end users?

Tags: django, vue.js, vuex, opayo

I'm currently working on a REST based SagePay Integration using a combination of Django on the backend and Vue / Nuxt on the front.

The current process is as follows:

1. Client makes a request to my backend server for a merchantSessionKey via a GraphQL resolver.
2. The backend graphene resolver uses the secret merchant integration key and password (stored in environment variables) to make a post request for the merchantSessionKey and returns it to the Vue frontend.
3. A user fills in the credit card form (using SagePay's [Own Form integration](http://integrations.sagepay.co.uk/content/getting-started-integrate-using-your-own-form))
4. I use the card data to generate a cardIdentifier that I will store in my vuex state and will use later to further the rest of the transaction.

Is this all safe to do? Obviously it will be secured via https and I will setup CORS properly when everything goes into production, but I am technically storing the merchantSessionKey and cardIdentifier on the end users machine.

Answer (score 0):

Both expire after 400sec and must be send together within Payment Registration POST authenticated with your vendor/account IntegrationKey and IntegrationPassword from your server which IP is whitelisted by Sage Pay. MSK is required to authenticate card tokenization call from customer's browser to Sage Pay endpoint. As a result you receive cardIdentifier/Token. This method keeps your server free of cardholder details but all (MSK,Token, PAN and CV2) are allowed to exist in customer browser.

IntegrationKey and IntegrationPassword can't be stored in the customer browser.

If you decide to use your own payment pages instead of drop-in checkout, you can't reference files from 3rd-party non-PCI DSS server to archive PCI DSS SAQ A-EP attestation.

I've reviewed it with QSA